# Change HTML page with Javascript but keep path unchanged

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use Javascript to open an HTML page which is in a sub-folder, but continue to have the path relative to my top level files. I have the code below and the HTML link works before the page is changed but not afterwards, because everything is then relative to the sub-page. If I click on the link after the page has been changed, it tries to open 'myFolder/myPage.html' which of course does not exist:

```
            .. in HTML

            <a href="myPage.html">My Page Link</a>

            .. in javascript

            var pageInFolder = 'myFolder/mySubPage.html';

            window.location.href = pageInFolder;
```

I could change my links to have absolute paths, but is there a way to display the page in the folder, but keep the path unchanged at my top level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HTML `<base>` tag. It lets you define where paths are relative to.

Something like:
`<base href="http://www.example.com">`

It is recommended that you put the base tag as the first tag inside the `<head>` so all paths in your file appear after it. With my example, even if you're in myFolder, any relative path will refer to http://www.example.com/myPage.html, not http://www.example.com/myFolder/myPage.html

Note though, this doesn't just apply to `<a href="">`. It applies to images, JavaScript files, CSS files, etc. Anything where you'd use a path.

Comment: That solved my problem. As I'm currently on localhost, I used:             <base href="http://localhost/myTopLevel/">                                           Note the slash after myTopLevel

Answer (score 0):

Just add / at the beginning of your relative paths

```
var pageInFolder = '/myFolder/mySubPage.html';
```